# Location Manager Crashing When Authorisation Not Accepted

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager, appdelegate

I am using my app delegate to request permission from my app users to use the location services. This is all working fine if the user accepts but if the user does not accept the app will go into a constant loop of crashing when it needs the location service and will not give them another opportunity to accept the permissions. I don't see what is causing it to crash but I will post the app delegate code, the error and the view code below.

ERROR

> [5091:2158600] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString
>   objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1000981a0'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x18176ee38 0x180dd3f80 0x181775ccc 0x181772c74 0x181670d1c 0x100083158 0x18699e844 0x18699de88
>   0x18699dc44 0x18699da50 0x186c08930 0x1869a39b0 0x1868b39c8
>   0x1868d9220 0x1868b36ac 0x1868b2c40 0x1820a0d50 0x1868b2ac4
>   0x1868c0578 0x1872570a8 0x1868f0e90 0x1869089c8 0x1869b9544
>   0x186c18740 0x186b6afd8 0x186b78990 0x1868aa4a4 0x1817247b0
>   0x181722554 0x181722984 0x18164cd10 0x182f34088 0x186921f70
>   0x100082a14 0x1811ea8b8) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught
>   exception of type NSException

appdelegate.m

```
@synthesize locationManager = _locationManager;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

    return YES;
}
```

view.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CLAuthorizationStatus authorizationStatus= [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];

    if (authorizationStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways ||
        authorizationStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse) {

        NSLog(@"test1");
        _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init]; //initializing locationManager
        _locationManager.delegate = self;
        [_locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]; //iOS 8 MUST
        _locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
        _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
         [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];  //requesting location updates
        [self downloadorders];
    }
    else{
         NSLog(@"test2");
        _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        [_locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        latitude=0;
        longitude=0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Set an exception breakpoint and see if you can identify the line where the exception is occurring. It doesn't look like it is in the code you have shown. Note, however, that once the user rejects location permission, the request dialog won't be shown again; the only way that the user can grant permission is through the settings app

Comment: Thanks for that Paul, solved my issue. I found out that I was stopping the downloadorders from running which was creating a new array then code that I had not shown was returning a count from the array but it wasn't setting when the downloadorders was stopped.